# Embed the middle of the tree chart

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good day everyone!

sorry for my poor english language

How can I put this chart tree in the **middle of the screen**?

I am using Twitter Bootstrap.

These are my html and css code:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.tree ul {
 padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
 font-family:'B Yekan', tahoma, Arial;font-size:12px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
 float: left; text-align: center;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
 right: auto; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
 display: none;
}
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
 border: 0 none;
}
.tree li:last-child::before{
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
.tree ul ul::before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
 display: inline-block;
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
 background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
 border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">main</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#">row2</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#">row3</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">row3</a>
</li></ul></li>
<li><a href="#">row2</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">row3</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">row3</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">row4</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">row4</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">row4</a>
</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></div>
```

How can I put this chart tree in the **middle of the screen**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to do that, but one of them is using `flex`. 
Add to your class `tree` this css:

```
.tree {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

Hope this helps!